# Magento - Move the "terms and conditions" from the last checkout step to the first one

Tags: magento

How can I move the terms and conditions from the last checkout step to the first one ?

I have tried only with the xml files, but I can't continue to the next step in this case.

Please help to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **`checkout.xml`**, move

```
<block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
```

from `<checkout_onepage_review>` handle into `<checkout_onepage_index>`:

You have to modify

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_billing" name="checkout.onepage.billing" as="billing" template="checkout/onepage/billing.phtml"/>
```

into

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_billing" name="checkout.onepage.billing" as="billing" template="checkout/onepage/billing.phtml"></block>
```

and put the line inside.

In **`info.phtml`** (or review.phtml for v1.4.2) cut

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('agreements') ?>
```

and paste that line you've just cut into **`billing.phtml`**.

Comment: Thank you OSdave,
I don't have `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('agreements') ?>` in my **info.phtml** file (I'm using Magento versiob 1.4.2), I have it only in **\checkout\onepage\review.phtml**. I have moved it, but it still don't works  ! :(

Comment: well, it's working for me in my 1.4.2 too. Have you refreshed the cache? are the conditions enabled? are you woring with onepage or multishipping? please explain what you've done. Also, put another coment next time, otherwise I'm not aware that there is new information, I've seen it by chance.

Comment: I don't find `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('agreements') ?>` in **info.phtml** file.

I' working with checkout onepage.The conditions are of course enabled, I have now refreshed the cache, I can see the block agreements.phtml but the problem is that I can go to the next step without checking the check box: the checkbox don't work and there is no pop-up message!

Comment: that's because the function binded to this checkbox is part or the Review js object, instanciated in review.phtml. You'll need to add it in the `new Billing()` declaration, and modify ths javascript and the controllers in order to get it working.

Comment: any help to make the necessary chnages with javascript and controllers to get it to work ?

Answer (score 1):

Long time done this post but those that are still in need:

To add to that contributed from @OSdave - as @Bizboss is saying the terms and conditions checkbox doesn't have to be checked to proceed to the next step. To provide a front end solution with least fuss just add `required-entry` to the class name - e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="agreement-<?php echo $_a->getId()?>" name="agreement[<?php echo $_a->getId()?>]" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_a->getCheckboxText()) ?>" class="checkbox required-entry" />
```

This employs JS validation to prevent it from proceeding to the next stage without being checked.